# Is it possible to have clang++ link dylib's relatively and not use install_name_tool?

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, dylib, clang++

### Summary

When linking an executable with a dylib, is `install_name_tool` the only way to make the dylib path relative to the executable, or is there a way of doing so in clang's linking step?

---

### Setup

Given the following project structure:

```
 - Project Root
    | compile.sh
    - lib_src
        | myprint.cpp
        | myprint.h
    - main_src
        | main.cpp
```

with these files: https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/8fa140b60b8ffeb2cae0

Running `compile.sh` (used instead of a make file for simplicity's sake here) results in the following files:

```
 - Project Root
    | main               (a unix executable linked to myprint.dylib)
    | myprint.dylib      (a dynamic library that main uses)
```

---

Running the program with `./main` while `cd`'d into the project works fine, but attempting to run it from anywhere else, such as by simply double clicking it, will result in the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: myprint.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Jo/Sandbox/libtest/main
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

When inspecting main with `otool` I can see that this is because the path for myprint.dylib is not defined in terms of the executable:

```
$ otool -L main
main:
    myprint.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

### The general fix

As far as I've been able to find out, the suggested way to fix this is by using `install_name_tool -change` and modify the path to use `@executable_path`:

```
install_name_tool -change myprint.dylib @executable_path/myprint.dylib main
```

---

### The Question

While the above fix clearly works, it seems somewhat unintuitive to me that there is no way of telling clang to just link `main` in such a way that it already uses the `@executable_path` to start with. It seems odd that when compiling a program with an arbitrary number of dylibs, that this has to be done for every single one.

Is this really the only way? Is this what cmake and xcode do under the hood? Is there a reason why we can't just have `clang++` link relatively rather than absolutely by default?

I have found some tools that make the process easier, such as the [mac dylib bundler](https://github.com/auriamg/macdylibbundler), but I'm curious if anyone has any insight as to *why* it is done this way.

---

## TL;DR

Is there a way to [change just this line](https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/8fa140b60b8ffeb2cae0#file-compile-sh-L14) to avoid having to run `install_name_tool -change`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed possible:

When compiling my library I set its `install_name` to be in terms of `@rpath`:

```
clang++ -dynamiclib lib_src/myprint.cpp -o myprint.dylib -install_name @rpath/myprint.dylib
```

And then in when compiling the executable I set `rpath` to be in terms of `@executable_path`, which can be done in a single step:

```
clang++ main_src/main.cpp -o main -I ./lib_src myprint.dylib -rpath @executable_path
```

For a detailed explanation of `@rpath` and `@executable_path` please check this wiki: https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath